# How do I use dynamically generated Nginx config files with Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am developing an application using Nginx and ExpressJS (NodeJS) and I am using Docker (with `docker-compose`)

I had not written the application keeping Docker in mind.

My application dynamically creates Nginx configurations. Originally, these Nginx configurations were placed in a standard directory within my application. I had configured Nginx to read all *.conf files from this directory and everything worked great.

Now that I am using Docker, I am using two different containers: One for Nginx and one for my application.

**Question:** How do I move the generated config files from one container to another?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run both your container mounting the same volume.
See "[Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)".

The first container would generate the configuration files in that volume.
The second container (NGiNX) would read them.

See as an example [Volume configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference):

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/db
  backup:
    image: backup-service
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/backup/data

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Here the same volume is mounted twice.

Answer (score 1):

All tough VonC solution will work, it may complicate your deployment process as both containers will need to be on the same server and share a persistent volume , which may then complicate state management and startup, unless you are using docker compose in production as well, you will also need service discovery for the services to find each other, which you may not need if you are only just trying to prototype a single service.

You can choose to run nginx alongside your express application in the same container using supervisord.

Here is a reference from the docker docs on how to do that:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

I think this could make sense for your use case if nginx is working as a supporting role to your express application and both services can be considered part of the same microservice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into your solution in the long term. For the short term solution, I used VonC's solution and it solved my immediate problem. I had one quick question: I am pretty new to Docker. Why would I not use docker-compose in production?

Comment: it depends on how and where you want to run your containers, docker compose 3 added support for multi host aware containers, but there are much more mature solutions out there to orchestrate running multiple containers alongside each other on multiple / redundant hosts. docker compose started out as a development tool for docker networks ( fig ) and still sort of is that I believe, lot's of work is bing done to take it closer to a production tool tough.